# How to create one time screen (like Terms and Condition screen) for Windows 8 metro style app using XAML and C#

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am new to Windows-8 metro app development, I am developing my app using XAML and C#. My objective is to create a screen (or some dialog) which will show some contents and user have to accept or exit.

On button Accept click further pages in application will appear and on exit, app will be terminated.

This screen(terms and condition screen) will never appear again after accepting for one time.

My question is, what is the best way to develop this type of screen, using Popup or XAML page or some other better way?

I am able to create a Popup (which doesn't look good) and XAML (which looks great).

Please advice.

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You decide which page shows up when the app first opens, so you can check whether your legal info page was already shown and accepted to decide whether to show it or not, so it can just be your first page after the application starts.

Comment: So you are suggesting separate XAML like EULA.xaml and it will be launched for App.xaml.cs?

Answer (score 2):

I think the Splash screen sample example in the sample app pack available at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples will have what you are looking for.